# spring AOP and proxy-target-class

Tags: spring, aop

I have abstract class of an interface to be backward compatible and reduce redundency.

```
abstract class EventHandlerAdapter implements EventHandler;
class ImplClass extends EventHandlerAdapter;
class Impl2Class extends EventHandlerAdapter;
```

I have AOP setting for transaction for any impl class inheriting from abstract class only.

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut id="EventTXOperation" expression="execution(* EventHandlerAdapter.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="EventTXOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

When I try to refer ImplClass in Impl2Class, even I specify proxy-target-class="true", it seems spring will always use original interface EventHandler and I cannot cast to abstract class or concrete impl. 
Is this normal behavior of spring AOP with proxy-target-class? I saw I can dive deep to use Advisor class to get target class of auto proxyed bean but seems it's invasive. So what kind of better option can I have?

Comment: I'm not sure your pointcut actually matches where you think it does (I expect `execution(* com.EventHandlerAdapter+.*(..))` is what you meant, if you really have `EventHandlerAdapter` in the "com" package).  So maybe there is another component creating a proxy of your impls that has `proxy-target-class="false"`?

Comment: package name is not an issue here as I just delete the company's name here. The class name is unique across code base and transaction works via AOP.

Comment: do you have cglib available on the classpath? You could also try turning up logging to debug/trace and see if it tells you anything relevant see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying